# nested collapse component gets opens when parent component is opened in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have make a vue collapse component in which there is a nested **transition component**
Here is the components

```
enter code here<template>
<div>
    <div class="collapse-trigger" @click="toggle"  >
        <slot name="trigger" :is-open="isOpened" ></slot>
    </div>

    <slide-transition-widget ref="slideTransition">
        <div class="collapse-content" v-if="isOpened">
            <slot ></slot>
        </div>
    </slide-transition-widget>
</div>
```

```
import slideTransition from './slide-transition';

    export default {
        props :{
            isOpen:{
                type : Boolean,
                default : true
            }
        },
        data (){
            return {
                isOpened : this.isOpen
            }
        },
        watch :{
            isOpen (newVal , oldVal){
                if(newVal)
                    this.open();
                else 
                    this.close();
            }
        },
        methods:{
            close(){
                this.isOpened = false,
                this.$emit('update:open' , this.isOpened);
                this.$emit('on-close' , this);
            },
            open(){
                this.isOpened = true,
                this.$emit('update:open' , this.isOpened);
                this.$emit('on-open' , this);                
            },
            toggle(){
                this.$refs.slideTransition.cancel();
                if(this.isOpened)
                    this.close();
                else
                    this.open();
            }
        },
        components :{
            'slide-transition-widget' : slideTransition,          
        }
    }



.collapse-trigger
    cursor: pointer
```

and this is the code to give life to components

```
enter code here                <collapse-widget class="card" key="1">
                <div class="card-header" slot="trigger" >
                    <div class="card-header-title">
                        Collapse                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2 class="subtitle">Subtitle</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis nemo dolorum repellat cumque temporibus, beatae neque maxime tenetur! Voluptates iure vitae cupiditate velit deleniti aut, quos sed. Labore, odio porro!</p>
                        <button class="button is-info">this is button</button>
                        <collapse-widget class="card" key="2" >
                            <div class="card-header" slot="trigger" >
                                <div class="m-10">
                                    Collapse                        
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <h2 class="subtitle">Subtitle</h2>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis nemo dolorum repellat cumque temporibus, beatae neque maxime tenetur! Voluptates iure vitae cupiditate velit deleniti aut, quos sed. Labore, odio porro!</p>
                                    <button class="button is-info">this is button</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </collapse-widget>            
                    </div>
                </div>
            </collapse-widget>
```

Now the problem is when i click the **trigger** slot of the parent component the nested collapse component also gets triggered it also gets expanded with it..
I dont know why this is happening..

Comment: You have them both bound to `isOpened`...

Comment: i found it the problem is with `v-if` when i changed it to `v-show` it worked.. but i cant get it why is this.